# What is the naming convention for this type of object

Tags: naming, naming-standards

I have frequent "access" classes that implement interfaces / abstract classes.

These classes all have different   classes/ dlls to execute the implemented method.

What naming convent is commonly used to mark these Interface / Access classes for a package/namespace?

as example:

```
namespace Kitchen
{
    interface IAppliance
    {
        void Use();
    }
    namespace Kitchen.Microwaves
    {
        abstract class Microwave : IAppliance
        {
            abstract public void Use();
            public bool CanCook()
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }   
    namespace Kitchen.Microwaves.Cooker6000
    {
        class Cooker6000 : Microwave
        {
            override public void Use()
            {
                //call some dll
            }
        }
    }

    namespace Kitchen.Microwaves.Waveblaster
    {
        class WaveBlaster : Microwave
        {
            public override void Use()
            {
                //DllHandler.StartBlasting();
            }
            private static class DllHandler
            {
                public static void StartBlasting()
                {
                    //do something
                    //call dll
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Class names shouldn't be verbs to begin with.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I know, this is just an example to make my point.

Comment: I think the name you are after is *"Driver"*.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Can you put that in an answer?

Comment: Are AccessWaveBlaster6000, AccessMicroChef etc methods of Microwave or are they classes? Would you please use normal language notarion instead of nested bullet listes?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Classes

Comment: Would you please use normal language notarion instead of nested bullet listes?  It doesn't look like a code snippet/sample to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43423/discussion-between-gismo-and-tulains-cordova).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If they have access to hardware, they can be called *"DeviceDrivers"* or *"Controllers"*.
- If they are just wrappers to DDL calls they are *"Façades"* or *"Adapters"*.